# Sequelize find or create for list of items

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize and do not understand much looked but did not find anything specific

```
// API Method
function SeederApi(req: Request, res: Response) {
  let request = req.body;
  let _model_methods = new ModelMethod();
  request.forEach((obj: any) => {
    const condition = { name: obj.username };
    const value = {
      name: obj.username ,
      short_text: obj.short_txt
    };
    _model_methods.findorCreate(condition, value)
      .then((resp: any) => {
        const _response = resp.get({ plain: true });
        console.log(_response);
      });
  });
    return res.status(200).send("Created");
}
```

```
export class ModelMethod{

  init(){}

  findorCreate = (condition: any, value: any) => {
    return Model
      .findOne({ where: condition })
      .then((obj : any) => {
        if(obj){ return obj }
        return RiskFactors.create(value);
      })
  }
}
```

The issue here is when 2 or more entries with the same username is in the list, it should return the obj rather than creating one. IT works fine if only one item is in the request. But when I have multiple items with possibly same username. It ends up creating duplicate entries as sequelize query is async but my loop is not.

I understand the issue here, I dont know to handle it.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

don't use forEach with async calls in its iterations.
Use a usual for of:

```
for (const obj:any of request) {
  const condition = { name: obj.username };
  const value = {
    name: obj.username ,
    short_text: obj.short_txt
  };
  const resp = await _model_methods.findorCreate(condition, value);
  const _response = resp.get({ plain: true });
  console.log(_response);
}
```